# How to add parent Model id in child Model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I want to put parent(On this case, "Users" ) id in child("Projects") when I create new project record.

Maybe the codes fail to get id in view.
Could you teach me what is lacking problem?

**Controller**

```
#users_controllers.rb
def create
  @user = User.new(name:params[:name])
  @user.save
  redirect_to("/")
end 

    #projects_controllers.rb

 12   def create
 13     @user = User.find_by(id: params[:id])
 14     Project.new(
 15       name: params[:name],
 16       user_id: params[:id])
 17   end
```

**Model**

```
#user.rb    
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :projects
end

#project.rb
class Project < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user, optional: true
end
```

**View**

```
#users.new.html.erb
<%= form_tag("/users", :method => :post) do %>
  <input name="name" value="<%= %>">
  <input type="submit" value="Registration">
<% end %>

#projects.new.html.erb
<%= form_tag(user_projects_path, :method => :post) do %>
  <input name="name" value= "" >
  <input type="submit" value="Create">
<% end %>
```

**Routing**

```
#routes.rb
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  root 'users#index'
  resources :users do
    resources :projects, shallow: true
  end
end
```

**Column**

```
2.0.0-p643 :001 > User.column_names
 => ["id", "name", "created_at", "updated_at"] 
2.0.0-p643 :002 > Project.column_names
 => ["id", "name", "created_at", "updated_at", "user_id"]
```

Comment: Which Rails version are you using?

Comment: Here is.
>>Rails 5.1.6

Answer (score 1):

In your view, you need to pass the user in the form path, like this: `user_projects_path(@user)`

However, if you want to link it to the logged in user, then it is not a good idea to pass around the user id, you directly have that available from your session, so you can use something like this in your controller:

```
#projects_controllers.rb
def create
  current_user.projects.new(name: params[:name])
end
```

If you don't have a current_user method available in your controllers, you might have user id stored in session, in which case your create action can be something like below:

```
def create
  user = User.find_by(id: session[:user_id])
  user.projects.new(name: params[:name])
end
```

Comment: Thank you Chirag.
1. I don't use log-in(Session method ) for this case.
2.

Comment: And I edited projects_controller.rb, I think that code line16 can get user id from line13. But can't.
I succeeded to create new instance and save it. But there is no "user_id".

Comment: @ShunOgawa there is no user id because you are not sending it from the view. You can log `params[:id]` in controller and see if it has any value or if it is blank

Comment: So, On 'project#new', I can get id of user as @user. But when I use same method in 'project#create',  @user.id will be "undefined method `id' for nil:NilClass"

How can I use User.id as Project.user_id ?

Comment: Can you update the controller code above to include projects#new method?
If you have the user id in projects#new, then you can update your form to include a hidden field to send back the user id, like: `<%= hidden_field_tag :user_id, @user.id %>`